# Unwanted space above text

Tags: html, css, html-table, whitespace

I'm trying to create a table with 2 cells, one with text, and one with a picture. And I don't know why, but I'm getting a very large unwanted space above the text.

**Here is the code:**

```css
.Table {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.Row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.PicDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 36px;
}

.TextDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="Table">
<div class="TableRow">
    <div class="PicDiv"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/crVTB6c/Pic.png"></div>

    <div class="TextDiv">
    Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the result that I'm getting:

https://i.ibb.co/7yBRNFb/Result.jpg

Why is that?

Comment: You can use `vertical-align: middle;`, also since your code is not really difficult to reproduce I'd suggest checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make a better question.

Comment: @Parco I'm getting the same result with vertical-align: middle; and vertical-align: top; , What is the different between this two? Also, can you edit my code and show me how should I have send it? Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Use can `vertical-align: top;` to align the text to the top of the element.

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align): `vertical-align` sets vertical alignment of an inline, inline-block or ***table-cell*** box.

EDIT: OP asked about a better way to have inline elements

I suggest [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

`display: flex;` allows you to align items in a directional flow by ***row*** or ***column*** using *sub-properties*. `justify-content` and/or `align-items`, depending on your [main-axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_main_axis), along with other styling attributes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: start;
}

.text {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="flex-cont">
    <div class="PicDiv"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/crVTB6c/Pic.png"></div>
    
    <div class="text">
    Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... 
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It did solved the problem :-) but is this tag known by all browsers? Also, why was there such a large space on the first place? It looks like as large the picture height is, the larger the space above the text. Why does the space above the text is influenced by a picture in another cell?

Comment: Likely because you are using display as table elements. Default table-cell vertical alignment is center I believe. So the table row you have is expanding the height to the content of the image, then when your text is filled, it seems as though there is white space within the containing element set to display as table-cell. Not sure why you are using those display methods...

Comment: `vertical-align` is an older css property and is fully supported by all browsers and is specific to ***inline***, ***inline-block*** and ***table-cell*** elements specifically.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm using the table tags because I want to have several cells one beside the other on the same line. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: But why table tags are wrong? Is there a problem with this tags?

Comment: It's not that they are wrong, unless there is a special case in using them, like your using a table. If you have content that calls for table data then use actual table elements, otherwise I see no reason to use those display properties personally.

Comment: See my updated answer showing an alternative to your use case with flex. I highly suggest reading and going through the MDN articles I have linked to on flex, it is a powerful tool for styling elements and is fully supported and really now-a-days a best-practice for CSS styling for aligning elements. There is also display ***grid*** as well ;) very powerful styling tools!

Comment: If you think my answer helped, please feel free to accept and happy coding. Also, you should think about moving to MDN site for tutorials and learning web fundamentals, much better resource than w3schools.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web